# How to add header connection close to flask

Tags: flask, python-requests, http-headers, webserver, flask-restful

I have a flask server that receives many connection from clients and it tends to keep those connection open which overload the server.

I want to add something like a middleware to close the connection and never keep any open connection alive. but not sure what is the easiest way to do it on flask